# How to update contents of multiple TD tags with a single JS event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a table with values.  I put a special `class` on some of them, indicating to me that when I press a button, all `<td>` tags that have that `class` update with a predetermined value.

Below is my non-working code.  The idea is when I press the button, all  tags that have `class="order"` update with a string, i.e. "Order Updated"

For background, I was able to do it with `id`, for when I only had one cell to update, but now I need to update more than one at once.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#mainTable").find("td").each(function() {
    this.html("Order Updated");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">Click to update Order</button>
```

Note:  code is non-working.

Comment: Change `$("#mainTable").find("td")` to `$("td.order")` ?

Comment: Try `$(this).html` not `this.html`

Comment: both suggestion worked!

Comment: Also `this.innerHTML = 'content';`

Comment: You can also use this way $("#mainTable td.order").html("Order Updated") instead of using each

Comment: @Dennis did my answer work as you wish?

Comment: both answers work I'm not sure which one to accept as both are correct

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, it should be `$(this)` then just add the special class to your `find()`

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#mainTable").find("td.order").each(function() {
   $(this).html("Order Updated");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">Click to update Order</button>
```

Comment: What about $("#mainTable td.order").html("Order Updated"); instead of each ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this `$("#mainTable td.order").html("Order Updated")` way instead of using each.

```js
$("#button").on("click",function() {
  $("#mainTable td.order").html("Order Updated");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="order">-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">Click to update Order</button>
```